# Watershed-segmentation with orfeo toolbox

Tags: qgis, watershed, orfeo-toolbox

[image: watershed segmentation]

I work at the moment with the watershed-segmentation from the orfeo-toolbox. After the segmentation the pictures is split into squares. Specially the square in the middle seems to be deeper the the rest of the picture, which doesn't confirm with the real topographic situation.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

You may have found a bug.

Can you please post a bug on the OTB bug tracker?

https://bugs.orfeo-toolbox.org/my_view_page.php

Please give the full command line and parameters which produce this output.

I would be nice also if yuo can provide the input image to reproduce the issue.

Thanks for the feedback.

Best regards,